# CSS fixed background positioning in table-cell

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-tables, cross-browser

There are 3 columns, the 2 side columns have to be expandable with the browser window, while the center is a fixed width.

You can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwF5B/

I cannot figure out how to get the background image on the left column to stay fixed when aligned to the 'bottom right' of the table-cell. The image is actually being aligned way more right than it is suppose to be and for some reason not aligning to the right edge of the cell.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't the problem that the background is the background of the `left-column` (dynamic width container), not `logo-wrap` (the fixed width cell)?

Comment: @zoli It should be in `left-column` because the image (the computer image in my link is a placeholder) is faded out on the left because it is fairly big, so it can't be constricted within the width of `logo-wrap`

Comment: Why not use divs for this? I don't understand the need for the a table here.

Comment: @enhzflep I suppose I could. The reasoning for a table was to easily have 100% height on each of the 3 columns.

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly the background image should show up? In your description, it'd be helpful to specify which cells you're referring to ('the cell', 'the table cell').

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have the background set as the background of .left-column, so it is the background of both cells within that cell. To fix this, set the background properties to the td #logo-wrap. Basically, the image is not aligned too far right, it's set as the background of the entire .left-column (including the table that has the #logo-wrap, which is what you want the background to be set for). Just add another css selector for #logo-wrap and set the image to that td's background.

Comment: The image can't be inside of `#logo-wrap` since said div is constricted to a specific width. The image needs to extend past `#logo-wrap` on the left side if the browser window is wide enough.